Selecting features buffered from the same shape, differenced by an exclusion, and then removing where it doesn't touch the original shape?
Let's say I have a shape (let's call this Shape)
I have developed a processing model that will buffer Shape (let's call this BufferedShape), and will then difference this from an exclusion zone (Exclusion).
From here, this model will split BufferedShape (Multipart to singlepart), thus meaning each BufferedShape will now have multiple features, where Exclusion has cut it. It then removes any of the feature that doesn't overlap or touch BufferedShape, by selecting by location and ensuring only areas that overlap are selected.
However, this has created issues where I have lots of features in Shape, as if there is lots of shapes on another side of an exclusion, it will not delete areas where this overlaps - is there any way to ensure that the only parts of BufferShape left are the ones that touch each of the original shapes they were buffered from?
I had thought of assigning a unique ID to each Shape, so that I can delete any of the BufferedShape that doesn't touch the Shape with the same ID, but this is where I am stumped, I'm not sure which function does this.
I've drawn this out below.
I want the buffered area of 1 to only include everything east of the black Exclusion. If 2 wasn't there, my function will automatically exclude the area to the west.
However, because 2 is there, when I select any overlap, it will select this western area as it overlaps with 2, thus keeping it in.


I have already used this as part of the processing model, this does not solve the issue above.
